# TL431 –parasitic capacitor

Tags: opto-isolator

I read this document from ON Semi, it said the optocoupler features a parasitic capacitor, does this Copto can find in the datasheet? I read the VO617A datasheet, but I don't find any capacitor value in the datasheet.

[image]

and I see the figure below.

[image]

There are my questions:

1.) Can I use this figure to get the parasitic capacitor value?

2.) I try to use this figure to calculate the capacitor value f=1/(2*pi*RL*C), when the RL=100, the C=7.9nF, when the RL=1000, the C=2.65nF. Does that mean the parasitic capacitor is not a constant value?

3.) In the datasheet, the coupling capacitance is Copto?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try, indeed, to extract the parasitic capacitance from the frequency response you've shown. For instance, if you take a resistance \$R_L\$ close to the one in the controller, assume 10 kohms, then you read the graph from the -3-dB point and infer a cutoff frequency of 3.5 kHz which would roughly imply a capacitance of \$\approx \frac{1}{2\pi\cdot10k\cdot3.5k}=4.5\;nF\$

However, it is rare that the pull-up resistance used in the data-sheet matches what you'll have on the board. Actually, what matters is the equivalent resistance "seen" from the feedback pin and, very often, there is an additional internal divider in the chip. The best is thus to extract this capacitance as excerpted below from my [APEC 2018](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202018.pdf) seminar:

[image]

You can use a network analyzer for doing so or a simple oscilloscope will do well as I explained in the seminar. The thing is to recreate the operating conditions of the opto with the selected controller. A dc source adjusts the bias to position the collector voltage at the same nominal level found in an operating board and you inject an ac modulation via the LED. The response observed on the collector will reduce in amplitude as frequency increases and you can determine the 3-dB cutoff frequency. When you have it, you can apply the above formula.

The coupling capacitance you mention, as its name implies, characterizes the parasitic capacitance between the primary and the secondary sides brought by the optocoupler.

Comment: Hi Verbal Kint 
Thanks for your answer. 

but if  RL=1k the C = 6.9nF, the value is different, so the Copto is not the constant value?

Comment: The parasitic capacitance depends on the Miller effect and other operating parameters from the internal bipolar transistor. You should go for a measurement on several samples as recommended. It is easy and fast then you know exactly where you are.

Comment: OK, I will do the experiment.
Can I remove the 4.7uF if I use the pure sine wave to inject the disturb in there?

Comment: The source is DC + AC?

Comment: Look, if you want to fix the collector voltage, you need a dc bias on the LED. Then, you superimpose an ac modulation to the LED current via the 4.7-µF capacitor. You can certainly combine an ac + dc offset from the generator but I've found that it was easier to fine-tune the operating point with a large resistance in series with the dc source.

Comment: I need to use min CTR value to calculate the resistor in Req right?

Comment: No, the \$R_{eq}\$ value is coming from the internals of your PWM controller. Look at the picture I gave in the reply. The resistance "seen" from the FB pin is actually \$R_{pullup}\$ || with \$R_1\$ + \$R_2\$. I have published this [book](https://www.amazon.com/Designing-Control-Linear-Switching-Supplies/dp/1608075575/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1350833636&sr=8-1) on the subject if you are in loop control of regulators.

Comment: Now I know the Req comes from, but why have two Req in the circuit one the C point the other connect A point, why the A point resistor also use Req?

Comment: This is arbitrary to have an overall low-frequency gain equal to the opto CTR. You can chose a different value for the resistance driving the LED, it does not affect the pole determination.

Comment: Now, I understand. Thanks for your answer.